# Samsung monitor not going into power saving mode

Tags: display, hdmi, power-management, powersave

I have recently bought a Samsung LT24D390 TV monitor, which I connected to my computer using a HDMI cable; the video card is a GeForce GTX 560 Ti, the O.S. is Windows 7 x64.

The monitor works as expected, but doesn't go into power saving mode when the computer tells it to do so; the computer is configured to put the monitor to sleep after 15 minutes of inactivity, and it does, but the monitor stays on and just displays a warning about no signal coming from the HDMI source. The same happens when the computer is shut down: the monitor keeps staying on.

I've fiddled a bit with the monitor config, and I found a setting to automatically turn it off when no signal is received from the current source; unfortunately, this can only be set as low as 15 minutes, so this means another 15 minutes of "no signal" warnings before the monitor finally shuts down; even more unfortunately, it looks like it actually ***shuts down***: when the computer resumes activity (or is powered on if it had been powered off), the monitor doesn't turn on on its own, and I have to manully turn it on using the power button or the remote.

I've looked around for a while, and I found several people having similar problems with HDMI connections, which are usually fixed by using a DVI connection; however, this monitor doesn't have any DVI port, it only has HDMI and VGA; and I most definitely don't want to connect it to a VGA port (which anyway isn't even present on my video card).

How can I make this monitor behave as it should, i.e. automatically going to sleep ***and*** coming back to life when it's supposed to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked Samsung's customer support, and they replied this is by design: the monitor is supposed to be turned on or off manually and has no power saving mode when connected via HDMI.

Comment: I know it's been answered a long time ago... but this is a total BS!